# if vs. whether (complementizer)

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar, government-and-binding

I'm studying syntax with '*Introduction to government and binding theory*' by Haegeman by myself and I encountered something I don't understand.

According to PRO theorem, PRO must be ungoverned. And these two sentences were presented.

> (a) *John doesn't know [if [PRO to leave]].
>   (b) John doesn't know [whether [PRO to leave]].

And he explains that in (a), *if* is the head and it governs PRO so the sentence is ungrammatical.
But in (b), *whether* is at the [Spec, CP] position so nothing governs PRO and the sentence is grammatical.

As I understood earlier, *if* and *whether* are samely complementizer. But how come *if* goes in [C, CP] while whether *goes* in [Spec, CP]? Why these two act differently and how can I tell it?

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks!
(If I posted this on the wrong place, please let me know. I'm not sure if I should go to English forum.)

Comment: Since non-terminal nodes never appear in the data, you can put whatever words you like in them. In this case, arranging things the suggested way makes this difference  (_whether_ can govern an infinitive VP, but _if_ can't) seem to fall out naturally, instead of being a random chunk of difference between two lexemes.

Comment: The query pro-forms have more functions than simple subordination.  'Whether' is a query pro-form for 'either', with the other choice (to stay) elided in your example.

Comment: In (b) "whether" is an interrogative subordinator introducing an interrogative infinitival. The meaning is deontic, as if the modal "should" were included: _John doesn't know whether he should leave_. By contrast, the subordinator "if" cannot introduce interrogative infinitives -- only subordinate content clauses (embedded questions) which (a) is not. Which explains why it is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In spite of what elementary textbooks tend to say, i.e., that the values of Comp are *that* (or 'null *that*'), *whether*, *if* and *for* (or 'null' *for*) in English, there is well established syntactic evidence that that initial analysis - dating back to the late 60's and early 70's - was **incorrect**.

As a matter of fact, *whether* is, like *when, why, where, how much, what book, under what conditions*, etc., a *wh*-**phrase** landing in Spec Focus, **not a Comp head**.

The simplest argument in this respect is that **whether** can be coordinated with other *wh*-**phrases** that must themselves occupy Spec Focus, whereas *if* cannot. Thus, in *I would like to know **whether and (,if so,) under what conditions** I could postpone payment of my teaching fees*, *whether* is clearly coordinated with a PP **phrase** and both land first in **Spec** Focus and then in **Spec** C (not in Focus and C!). Or, to take a different example, *whether* can also be coordinated with *not*, as in *I would like to know **whether or not** I am admitted to the AI programme*, where **not** is independently known to be a phrase base-generated in Spec Polarity (but not in the head of Polarity, as initially assumed). On the contrary, *if*, a C head, cannot be so coordinated, cf. * *I would like to know **if or not** I am admitted to the AI programme*.

Confirming evidence is available if you consider the etymology of *whether* (from OE *hw-aeither*) - or, for that matter, that of *not* (from *n(e)+a+wiht*, approximately 'not a bit', a negative **noun phrase**). Significantly, in Old and Middle English, *hwaether* did **not** interfere with the ascension of the finite verb into the head of FocusP. Although it is true that the finite verb did **not have** to ascend in *hwaether*-introduced clauses, and did not usually do (as in Modern English), the OED still cites quite a few OE and ME examples in which it **does**, yielding the word order *...hwaether* + Verb + Subject...).

Of course, if *hwaether* had been a C (or Focus) **head**, such verb-raising would **not** have been possible in **any** case, because the finite verb is itself a head and can raise only into an empty head position (= Head Movement). Consequently, *hwaether* was already a specifier, as it is today, in Old and Middle English.

Comment: Thank you! It's weird that this book explains that the values of Comp are _that_, _if_, _whether_, _for_ (as you mentioned) and says nothing about that _whether_ is a type of _wh_-phrase. It helped me a lot anyway!

Comment: You are right, especially because the idea that 'whether' is just another interrogative WH-element and that 'yes/no [= polarity] questions are just a particular case of 'wh-questions' dates back to Katz & Postal's 'An Integrated Theory of Linguistic descriptions' (MIT, 1964) (see chapter 4, pp. 95-97 and ff., in particular). What disguises this fact is that 'whether' (< wh+either-yes or not) questions the value of the POLARITY of the clause, a sentence adverbial, which is phonetically null when positive (= unmarked), although visible as the Polarity specifier 'not' when negative (= marked).